# Do images still need to be preprocessed when using tflite in an app?

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, flutter, tensorflow-lite

When saving a tensorflow-lite model, does extra information get saved *as well as the model architecture?* For example, image size, range of pixel values, etc.

Suppose that my model was trained on *normalized* images that had an *RGB* spectrum and were *100* **100* pixels in size.
Do I need to explicitly preprocess the images before performing inference in Android Studio / Flutter? Or does the tflite plugin automatically do this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to preprocess the images in your app side to the same format as the images used for training, before passing them to the TFLite model.

An example of this preprocessing step is explained here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/EXPLORE_THE_CODE.md#pre-process-bitmap-image